# Processing params into fetched objects

Tags: react-native, async-await, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React Native v0.63+ and React Navigation 5 with Firebase integration. I must solve two problems that involve Deep Linking to certain parts of an app that, in order to render the view, need some `props.route.params`-contained objects like `profile`, which might or might not hold sensible data to put in plain text url.

In order to navigate to a certain profile without having the whole profile stringified into an unending url, i thought that i could parse the `id` into the `profile` that must be fetched from api in order to be renderized by the view. However i misunderstood the `react-navigation` `parse` functionality.

However, i'm having trouble to figure out the correct way to do it. How do i do this?

Here is my `linking` object:

```js
export const linking = {
    prefixes: ['myapp://'],
    config: {
        Login: 'login',
        Signup: 'signup',
        PersonalInfo: 'personalinfo',
        Drawer: {
            path: "app",
            screens: {
                Saved: "saved",
                Details: "details",
                Trend: "trend",
                Profile: {
                    path: "profile/:id?",
                    parse: {
                        id: Number, // <-- this is my profile id param
                    },
                },
                EditProfile: "editprofile",
                Multimedia: "multimedia",
                Premium: "premium",
                Chat: "chat",
                LikeView: "likes",
                ReseedView: "reseeds",
                Tabs: {
                    path: "tabs",
                    exact: true,
                    screens: {
                        Main: "main",
                        Escribir: "escribir",
                        Notificaciones: "notificaciones",
                        Mensajes: "mensajes"
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

And this is how the app already processes the incoming `profile` to render it:

```js
//from any component within navigation reach
navigation.push('Profile',{profile, isMine});
```

```js
//Profile component
const ProfileScreen = (props) => {
  const { profile, isMine } = props.route.params;
  const [profileOwner, setProfile] = useState(profile);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to always use your params using **destructuring your props object.** It's a default ES6 syntax for javascript objects.

```
For Ex :

    const { isMine } = props.route.params;
```

So, I would suggest you to follow this approach for destructuring and using your objects even for initialising or manipulating inside your component rather than directly accessing whole param object like **"props.route.params.profile"**

Comment: I've applied your suggestion. Do you have any idea how to approach the main issue though?